# MySQL - Nullable field doesn't have a default value

Tags: mysql

I create a table like:

```sql
create table test(
   id int primary key,
   volume int null default 0
)
```

After I drop the default value of `volume`, `INSERT INTO test(id) VALUES (1)` throws error **[HY000][1364] Field 'volume' doesn't have a default value**, but `INSERT INTO test(id, volume) VALUES (1, NULL)` not.

Then I execute `alter table test change column volume volume int null`, the above two insertion scripts run well.

What's the difference between the two insertion scripts? And why setting nullable field to nullable redundantly can avoid the error?

Answer (score 0):

Define your table as

```sql
CREATE TABLE test(
  id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO INCREMENT,
  volume INT DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY USING BTREE (id)
);
```

A field can either have the `NOT NULL` constraint - or it **must** have a *default* value of NULL.